# Why do I get a negative values if I divide two positives ones?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using the following code to find a positive factor:

```
[U S V] = svd(image, 'econ'); % calculate the SVD of the image

level = 4;
factorJND = jnd(image, level) ; % calculate the JND values of the image
f = factorJND / abs(U*V)  % divide the JND value by the multiplication of U and V matrices( they have the same size)
```

Knowing that factorsJND and abs(U*V) are both positive, it gives me positive and negative numbers!! I don't know why!

```
f = -7.2851    6.4520
    -7.7509    5.5236
    -7.3374    4.1684
    -5.6905    5.0915
```

I even try to do :

```
f = abs(factorsJND) / abs(U*V)
```

But still gives me the same result while it should be all positive values!

Comment: I don't see where your assign `U`, `S` and `V`.

Comment: U,V and S are the singular vectors and value respectivelly coming from applying the singular value decomposition on the image.

Comment: Did you want `/` or `./`? `/` is basically `*inv(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [matrix right division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html) (`/`) rather than [an element-wise division](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html) (`./`). Because of this, it is possible that the result will have negative values for two inputs in which all values are themselves all positive values. You likely element-wise division instead.

```
f = factorJND ./ abs(U*V);
```

Comment: Yes @Suever, you are right. I didn't pay attention to that. thank you